# Uncaught TypeError: markersData[key].forEach is not a function

Tags: javascript, php, json

I have the following PHP code

`echo "<input id='json_data' name = 'json_data' type='hidden' value='" . json_encode($array) . "'/>";`

Which I then pull in a javascript file by using

```
    var markersData = document.getElementById('json_data')
```

I then try to run a ForLoop based on the data that I pull which gives me the "Uncaught TypeError: markersData[key].forEach is not a function."

```
markersData[key].forEach(function (item) {

}
```

I've seen many articles on the site that point to it being an issue with the getElementById giving it a HTMLCollection format instead of an o array. I tried to convert the HTMLCollection back to an array by using

```
var markersData = document.getElementById('json_data')
console.log(markersData);
            
var markersDataArr = Array.prototype.slice.call(markersData)
console.log(markersDataArr);
```

The top console.log shows the array correctly with some data in it, but the bottom one returns an empty array. I'm sure it's something simple, I'm new to Javascript and I'm a bit lost, I've been looking through articles most of the day but can't seem to find something that works for me.

For those interested in the JSON being posted across, it does seem to be all OK, I ran it in a json compiler without any issues.

```
[{"type_point":"Italian Food","name":"ABC123","location_latitude":"48.837273","location_longtitude":"48.837273","map_image_url":"img\/thumb_map_single_restaurant.jpg","rate":"Superb | 7.5","name_point":"Restaurant Name","get_directions_start_address":"","phone":"+3934245255","url_point":"detail-restaurant.html"}]
```

Comment: Updated, added console.logs

Comment: If you read the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById), you'll se that `getElementById` does not return an `HTMLCollection`, but rather an `Element` object, so it's normal it can't be turned into an array. Seems to me like you need to take that element's value and then do some processing with it.

Comment: Hi did you parse your json when using inside js ?  Also get value of input box using `document.getElementById('json_data').value`

Comment: @Swati - I tried to assign a variable using parse without using getElementById but it kept getting errors, wasn't sure if I was able to or if I just had the syntax wrong. 

Ideally if I could get the json straight into the MarkersData object without having to convert from an element, so I could then run the loop I posted above, but I'm struggling to see how to do that.

Comment: Do `console.log(document.getElementById('json_data').value)` see what does this shows .You will see output inside your browser console tab.

Comment: @Swati - Yeah thanks, so this definitely helped the final output, the console.log is now in the format I want, `{"Marker":[{"type_point":"Italian Food","name":"ABC123","location_latitude":"48.837273","location_longtitude":"48.837273","map_image_url":"img\/thumb_map_single_restaurant.jpg","rate":"Superb | 7.5","name_point":"Restaurant Name","get_directions_start_address":"","phone":"+3934245255","url_point":"detail-restaurant.html"}]}`  But still getting the same error as title, is there an extra step I need to do to convert it to an object?

Comment: Yes , do `$.parseJSON(document.getElementById('json_data').value)` and then access them.

Comment: @Swati - Perfect, thank you so much, it reads the array on console the exact same way as I had it when I manually entered the inputs for the array. You can add it as an answer. Could I message you and ask one more thing also, slightly related to this. Thanks!